# using the maps package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I've attached the code below and could use some help

1. compute the average arrival delay by destination from the flights data
2. join on the airports data to get the longitude and latitude of each destination
3. plot each destination with the average arrival delay mapping to the size or color aesthetic (map a continuous variable to color or size will generate a bar in the legend)
4. add the borders of the states and change the coordinate using coord_quickmap()

I've also added the expected plots below

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)
library(ggplot2)

airports %>%
  semi_join(flights, c("faa" = "dest")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat)) +
  borders("state") +
  geom_point() +
  coord_quickmap()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is currently not reproducible as we do not know where you have obtained your datasets. Please edit your question and add `library(package)` for each package you use. :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're more likely to get help if you try to ask only one question at a time.